# MVC Custom Validation String Array Client Side

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, customvalidator

There are examples out there of custom MVC validators that take an array parameter, but only server side - none of them show an example of implementing the client side with array parameter.

The problem is instead of outputting the array's contents in the html data- attribute, it outputs "System.String[]":

data-val-total-propertynames="System.String[]"

Here is my attribute class:

```
public class TotalAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private String[] PropertyNames { get; set; }              

        public TotalAttribute(String[] propertyNames)
        {
            PropertyNames = propertyNames;                      
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            float total = 0;

            foreach (var propertyName in PropertyNames)            
                total += (float)context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (total != (float)value)
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });            

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
                ValidationType = "total",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters["propertynames"] = PropertyNames;

            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

Here it is implemented in the model:

```
[Total(new string[] { "SomeOtherField1", "SomeOtherField2" }, ErrorMessage = "'Line12Balance' must equal total of 'SomeOtherField1' and 'SomeOtherField2'")]
public decimal? Line12Balance { get; set; }
```

Here is the html data-val attribute output:

```
data-val-total-propertynames="System.String[]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `"System.String[]"` string because the value of `ValidationParameters["propertynames"]` is written by calling `ToString` on it, so `string[]` variable returns `"System.String[]"` in this case. If you need to output specific value you need to format it by yourself in your validation attribute. For example, change

```
rule.ValidationParameters["propertynames"] = PropertyNames;
```

to

```
rule.ValidationParameters["propertynames"] =  string.Join(",", PropertyNames);
```

and you will get

```
data-val-total-propertynames="SomeOtherField1,SomeOtherField2"
```

Comment: awesome thank you. now i have to convert the comma deliminated string to array in the client side handler?

Comment: `var value = "SomeOtherField1,SomeOtherField2";
var arr = value.split(",");`

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Maybe my post can be used as an example to help others.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander mentioned in his answer, the issue you encountered is that `string[]` doesn't have its own `ToString()` implementation, and uses the base `object.ToString()` implementation, which just displays the type of the object rather than the contents of your array.

So you've got to somehow serialize your string array so that it can be stored in a string to then parse in your client-side JavaScript.

If you're already using JSON.Net in your solution (as many are), you can also do this by JSON serializing the array on the server side, then parsing the JSON client-side.

i.e. server-side:

```cs
rule.ValidationParameters["propertynames"] =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PropertyNames);
```

Client-side: (

```js
$.validator.addMethod('rule', function(value, element, params) {
    var propertynames = JSON.parse(params.propertynames);
    // do your validation
});
```

That prevents you from having to escape commas/delimiters in your parameters.